# Processing and pixels

Tags: processing, pixel, movie

I want to create a simple filter using the MOVIE class in processing. However, I have an issue with the size of the movie. The filter is a work in progress, please don't judge me :)

```
import processing.video.*;

Movie theMov; 
int size;

void setup() { 

  theMov = new Movie(this, "fargo.mp4");
  theMov.play();
  theMov.read();
  size(displayWidth, displayHeight);
  noStroke();
  size = 10;
}

void draw() { 
  //image(theMov, 0, 0, width, height);
  theMov.loadPixels();
  for (int i = 0; i < theMov.width; i+=size) {
    for (int j = 0; j < theMov.height; j+=size) {
      color c = theMov.pixels[i+j*theMov.width];
      fill(c);
      rect(i, j, size, size);
    }
  }
  updatePixels();
  size = (int)random(10, 20);
} 

void movieEvent(Movie m) { 
  m.read();
}
```

How would I do this if I want the movie to be fullscreen? As it is now it only fills a small portion of the screen. What I want is to be able to render the film fullscreen so that the loadPixels() function loads the film fullscreen.

Comment: I see what you're trying to do (if I understand this correctly) but unfortunately the Movie class is very limited. You can definitely resize the video and make it take up the whole screen using `image(theMov, 0, 0, width, height);` but that is not going to have any affect whatsoever on your pixel calculation since it doesn't permanently change the size of the video frame. The Image library has a resize function that doesn't work on video but you *could* convert your video to a sequence of images, use resize on them and then read them in a stream to do your operation...

Comment: That is convoluted really but I don't know any other way of doing this short of using an external library that can handle permanently converting a video's size to your desired size. If it were me and I needed a *quick* fix then I would go with creating a method that converted the video to image sequence and then read it back in a sequence and do the pixel operation. But that would be a quick fix and not something permanent.

Comment: That's a shame, but isn't there a way to resize a movie? That should be a basic method, shouldn't it?

Comment: There should be, there is one for images called `resize()` but an equivalent doesn't exist for videos. But I'll look around and see if I'm missing something and get back. Otherwise hopefully someone else can suggest something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are "drawing" each frame rectangle by rectangle you can simple calculate new ''position' and  'size' for these rectangles:

```
float ratioX = (float)width / theMov.width;
float ratioY = (float)height / theMov.height;
```

Depending on your aspect ration you should change this calculation. And then simple draw rectangle with new 'size' on new 'position':

```
rect(i * ratioX, j * ratioY, size * ratioX, size * ratioY);
```

Comment: Thanks Majlik, but could you explain a little more how and why this works? I don't understand what you are doing?

Comment: In theoretical basics it is [linear interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation) used to resize image (array of pixels). Or using intuition you want to draw bottom right (maximum) pixel from video frame into maximum pixel in canvas etc for all pixels but in your case we can increase size of "pixels" because you use rectangles so we use same ratio to increase size of whole video. If you do not use this filter you shall use more sophisticated method to resize frames ... [like this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_scaling)